# How can I refasten loose vinyl trim boards?

Tags: windows, exterior, siding, fastener, weather-resistant

The Azek vinyl paneling on my external windows has bowed out (both at the top and the bottom). It was being held by trim nails which were just too short. What's the appropriate fix here? Can I reusing this pieces and simply screw them in? What kind of screw would I use? Exterior 3"? (You will notice that the bottom piece has also bowed out.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what it is being screwed into.

If it is wood, use [trim screws](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Grip-Rite-6-x-1-5-8-in-Black-Phosphate-Trim-Interior-Trim-Screws-1-lb/3054035?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-hdw-_-ggl-_-LIA_HDW_126_Fastening-_-3054035-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjw_aemBhBLEiwAT98FMoN119tUg4OO8cMTACGHs_62ohTJcswgUOo8K69xfl_OyuciNq9b-xoCQIwQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)  If it's aluminum the same trim screws can be use but a pilot hole must be drilled.

The screws come in different lengths and colors, but the black would suit you well. They set nicely and a dab of caulk and touch up paint and you are done.

Comment: Would it matter if it's not an exterior screw? And can I reuse the same pieces and count on the screws to straighten them out?

Comment: You can reuse the same pieces. The screws don't need to be exterior. The Azek is Doesn't degrade screws. A dab of caulk over the head will seal things.